# Best run to do Exp wise?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm quite underlevel right now so I'm wondering, what should I run to exp up?

I'm halfway in Act3 on Nightmare, so I can't go back to normal diablo, that would not be worth the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to "run" an area. You can't really get behind in levels if you're able to complete the Acts.

If you feel behind in exp, just restart the Act.

If you feel behind in *power*, that's a different matter. It's more likely you need better gear or to see if some of your other skills might be more effective currently.